# Openshift Volume Mounts showing root:root

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to run a SonarQube pod in Openshift but it seems to be mounting the persistent volume with root as the owner.

How can we change this to a non-root user?
I created my persistent volume with 'hostPath'.

You can find some more information below:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /opt/sonarqube/data/es
at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.(NodeEnvironment.java:169)
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:165)
... 6 common frames omitted
```

Here is the sonarqube directory screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please copy-paste the text of the screenshot in the question. Images that link to other websites might vanish, which would make this question incomplete on a later time.

Comment: Here is the link to my yaml - [link](https://gist.github.com/deepjyotsingh/67d8accfa6eac42deba717300a2ad37d)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a specific `securityContext` to

- change the group of mounted filesystems
- change the user a pod is run as
- pass SELinux options.

https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/persistent_storage/pod_security_context.html offers some more background.

This setting is done in your DeploymentConfig. The key `securityContext` should already be present. With the following, the directory should be group-writable:

```
securityContext:
  fsGroup: <GROUPID OF SONAR>
```

Comment: Thanks @kronn. I've tried various combinations without much success. Would you please review my yaml and suggest changes?

Here is the link to my yaml file - [link](https://gist.github.com/deepjyotsingh/67d8accfa6eac42deba717300a2ad37d)

Comment: Seems okay to me. The indentation of line 108 is a bit unusual. I would just indent it 2 spaces more than line 107, yaml is usually indented with spaces, not tabs.